# MySQL Subqueries

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

I was wondering if something like this is possible in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tmpTable WHERE id = 1 AND ISTRUE(UPDATE tmptTable SET value = 1)
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM tmpTable WHERE id = (INSERT INTO tmptTable (name) VALUES ('test'))
```

Or the same query with UNION or something

What i'm trying to do with this is SELECTing only the records that are updated/by the ID's they are inserted. I want to know if it's acutally possible to do an Update or Insert query INSIDE an other query.

Comment: what are you trying to do, in plain English?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do [composable DML](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2009/04/08/Composable-DML.aspx). No this isn't supported in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to do composable DML. No this isn't supported in MySQL. – Martin

https://stackoverflow.com/users/513811/martin

He just gave the answer, but as a comment...